# Compressing only files using 7z without preserving the path

Tags: command-line, 7zip

I am using 7z command line executable to zip files, but I see that while adding to an archive the path of the files is preserved in the archive.

So if I do

```
7z a -tzip  myzip.zip dir1\dir2\*
```

the archive myzip.zip will contain the path dir1\dir2. I do not want this, rather I want only the files to be added to the zip file without the paths being preserved.
I searched quite a bit but do not seem to find any way of doing this, maybe I am missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Give the full path. That should work. Not the relative path from the current location.
For example, I give the below, where I want the files in the man5 folder to be archived.

```
$ 7z a -tzip myzip.zip /home/pradeeban/Desktop/man4/man5/*
```

The zip contained only the files, without the directories.

Then I gave only the relative path. It had the directories, inside the zip.

```
$ 7z a -tzip myzip.zip Desktop/man4/man5/*
```

Tried with Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). Not sure whether that differs from Windows.

Comment: +1 It works in Windows. I had exactly this problem, and exactly this solution worked.

Comment: Adding the full path requires you (most likely) to look that up. The solution Nicklay O. is providing is more convenient. It only requires you to add a dot in front of the path.

Comment: NOTE: according to the same [7z manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/7z) `dir1/dir2/*` **excludes** all hidden files (like `dir1/dir2/.htaccess`).

Comment: A note about note by @Kamiccolo
Using shell wildcard expansion, typing `dir1/dir2/*` in the terminal emulator, indeed excludes dotfiles, however, this has nothing to do with `7z` behaviour, it's done by your shell. According to my tests, however, if you literally pass the argument `dir1/dir2/*` (like `7z a  myzip.zip "dir1/dir2/*"`), it adds all files, _including_ dotfiles (hidden files).

Comment: Inconsistent behaviour then *sigh*

Answer (score 98):

Just add a dot before the path, i.e.
`7z a -tzip -r myzip.zip .\Relative\Dir\*`

Comment: Yeah, for *nixes slash should be like this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! It even works when file paths are specified in external list. Tested with 7-Zip 16.04 on Windows.

Comment: Thanks guys for feedback. I'm getting so much fun of the fact that 'put the dot before' is my top answer on StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Could someone please explain why this works?

Comment: Why this `7z a -r x.zip ".\relative\dir\*"` works?
And why this `7z a -r x.zip "relative\dir\*"` doesn't?

Comment: The answer should be buried somewhere here: https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip/blob/master/CPP/Windows/FileName.cpp

Answer (score 15):

I discovered a way to do this by using a relative path:

```
7z a -tzip  myzip.zip %CD%\dir1\dir2\*
```

%CD% is how you get the current path in a Windows batch file, but it also works from the command line. More info about [Capturing the current directory from a batch file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/28/362565.aspx).

Comment: worked for me (on command prompt, windows 10)

Answer (score 3):

As explained in related question in [7-zip user FAQ](http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html#user_faq), 7z stores paths relative to working directory, so you will need to first `cd` to desired top-level directory for archive and run 7-zip from here.

```
cd dir1\dir2\
7z a -tzip  myzip.zip *
```

If you run it from script and don't want to affect it with changed directory, use directory push/pop facilities available in your shell of choice or run cd+7-zip in spawned process to avoid affecting your entire script with changed directory. For example, using Windows' start that would be:

```
start /D dir1\dir2\ /wait 7z a -tzip  myzip.zip *
```

Comment: I am running this in a script and do not want to change directory. Is there no other way of doing the same?

Comment: You will have to, because that's how 7z works. Use directory push/pop facilities available in your shell of choice or run cd+7-zip in spawned process to avoid affecting your entire script with changed directory.

Comment: thanks for the creative solution, but as Kathiravelu points out giving the full path does the trick.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution if you need to preserve a part of the path

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

Consider folder structure like C:\Parent\SubFolders..... And you want to create parent.zip which will contain all files and folders C:\Parent without parent folder [i.e it will start from SubFolders.....]

```
cd /D "C:\Parent"

"7z.exe" a Parent.zip "*.*" -r
```

This will create Parent.zip in C:\Parent