# How can I archive multiple Folders into a single Zip File using 7zip C#?

Tags: c#, 7zip

I have Multiple folder path:

```
SourceFilePath="C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\PSI"
SourceFilePath1="C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\Google"
SourceFilePath2="C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\Isp"
```

I want to Compress These path Using 7zip Command line code along with a Zip Password.

Edit:

```
     //Declare and instantiate a new process component.
                    System.Diagnostics.Process proc;
                    proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

                    //Do not receive an event when the process exits.
                    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;


                    //The "/C" Tells Windows to Run The Command then Terminate 
                    string strCmdLine;
                    strCmdLine = "/C cd c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\ ";
                    strCmdLine += " & 7z a  "// here i need help 

                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);

                    proc.Close();
```

What I actually Did:

```
 var MultiplePathFolders=SourceFilePath+SourceFilePath1+SourceFilePath2
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc;
  proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
   string strCmdLine;
     strCmdLine = "/C cd c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\ ";

      strCmdLine += " & 7z a " + SyncPath + "\\" + ZipName + "-FileName.7z " + MultiplePathFolders + " -p" + DecryptedPassword + "";

  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);

   proc.Close();
```

Comment: did you tried .. http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip

Comment: We are here to solve errors in your code. We are not "free code writing service". Show us what you've tried and then we will able to help you out.

Comment: Same here. OK i i give u what i have tried so far

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19282233/1928632) after putting all 3 folders in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
string yourPassWord = "Hello";
string yourZipPath="D:\\my7z.7z";                      // Your 7z file path
//string yourZipPath="D:\\myZip.zip";                  // Or your zip file path
System.Diagnostics.Process proc;
proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

List<string> foldersAndFiles = new List<string>();
foldersAndFiles.Add("D:\\F1");                        // Add folder
foldersAndFiles.Add("D:\\F2");                        // Add folder
foldersAndFiles.Add("D:\\file.txt");                  // Add file

string cmd = "a -tzip -p\"" + yourPassWord + "\" \"" + your7zPath + "\"";
foreach(var item in foldersAndFiles)
{
    cmd += " \"" + item + "\"";
}

proc.StartInfo.FileName
    = "c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe";            // Be sure this file exist.
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
proc.Start();

proc.Close();
```

Comment: It works . But i have found myselft a better soultion than this. thanx Sakura :)