# Is it possible to compress files without keeping the structure in Linux?

Tags: linux, 7zip

I have the following directory structure:

```
A0
├── A1
│   ├── A1_B1
│   │   ├── A1_B1_1.docx
│   │   ├── A1_B2_2.pptx
│   ├── A1_B2
│   │   └── A1_B2_C1
│   │       ├── A1_B2_C1_D1
│   │       │   ├── A1_B2_C1_D1_1.docx
│   │       │   └── A1_B2_C1_D1_2.docx
│   │       └── A1_B2_C1.xlsx
├── A2
└── A0.txt
```

I want to create a .7z file that will contain only the files. I don't want to keep the folders. I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10754691/13010940) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13051179/13010940) but they don't work in Linux. 
Is it possible to do it with `7z` or I should extract files to a single directory first and then compress.

Comment: Could you please show us the command you've tried?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: If you have two files named the same way in two different paths, you will have trouble with that approach.

Comment: I have tried a few things: 1. `7z a  A0.7z /u/anipet/Desktop/A0/*` 2. `7z a -tzip  A0.zip /u/anipet/Desktop/A0/*` 3. `7z a -tzip -r A0.zip ./A0/*`, etc.

Comment: @kikito Yes, I am aware of that. All the files have unique names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason the answers you reference to don't work try this instead.

Create a directory

```
mkdir flat_dir
```

Link all files from the desired folder recursively in `flat_dir`, for me the desired folder was `cpptest`.

```
for full_path_file in $(find ../cpptest -type f)
do
echo "$full_path_file"
filename=$(echo "$full_path_file" | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev)
echo "$filename"
ln -s -T "$full_path_file" "$filename"
done
```

Zip the files

```
7z a test.zip -l ~/flat_dir
```

Comment: I liked the idea of creating a directory of symbolic links. Thank you!